# Worksheet_Change event for multiple external workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, class, events

I have a class module that acts as a Worksheet_Change event for an external workbook. I am reworking my project, and the current setup only allows for one external workbook sheet_change event. I would, however, like this event listen for changes on multiple workbooks.

The amount of workbooks is unknown until midway in the code, so I can't create a predetermined amount of classes for each workbook.

Module `Functions`:

```
Dim oWb2 As New UpdaterUnkowns

Public Function
'Code...
Set oWb2.Workbook = newfile
End Function
```

Class module `UpdaterUnknowns`:

```
Public WithEvents m_wb As Workbook
Public CellVal As String

Public Property Set Workbook(wb As Workbook)
    Set m_wb = wb
End Property

Public Property Get Workbook() As Workbook
    Set Workbook = m_wb
End Property

Public Sub m_wb_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

'Code...

End Sub
```

`Set oWb2.Workbook = newfile` sets the workbook for the class module. Could I pass multiple workbooks to the event?

Comment: Classes aren't exactly my thing, but can you create a collection of those workbooks and pass that? And then use a `For Each` to set what you want...Ignore this if sounds stupid or already tried and doesn't work.

Comment: you can put your module to multiple workbooks

Comment: Or create a collection with multiple instances of your class. Depends what you need to achieve.

Comment: Could you expand @Rory?

Comment: @FAB I'll have a look

Comment: Create multiple instances of your class, with one workbook assigned to each, and add them to a collection. Each one will then monitor one workbook.

Comment: TimStack as far as I can test, passing the collection is a no go. Sorry couldn't help here.

Comment: No worries @FAB, I appreciate the help

Comment: @Rory doesn't that mean I will have to create multiple class modules? Sorry if I don't follow. Perhaps it's better if you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle every open workbook, you could do something like this:

```
Dim UU_collection As Collection
sub mysub()
   Set uu_collection = New Collection
   Dim wb As Workbook
   For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
      Dim oWb2 As UpdaterUnknowns
      Set oWb2 = New UpdaterUnknowns
      Set oWb2.Workbook = wb
      uu_collection.Add oWb2
   Next wb
End Sub
```

Comment: Seeing as how the loop would, with each iteration, create another class instance (with `newfile` as the class' workbook), what is the use of the collection in this case?

Comment: It holds references to all the class instances so that they persist after the sub has run.

Comment: @TimStack, so a collection was the answer after all... just not quite how I've imagine it.